# How to preview a file in html using file path as argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

The application that I am working now require a functionality in such a way,
on click of preview button,the respective file should be previewed in a div.

**I have anchor tag:**
`<a href={{item.url}}><b>{{item.fileName}}</b></`a>

data binding is in angualr js.

onclick of the filename the file path associated with it should go to the preview method as below:

But i am unable to do it for all the file extensions and I dont feel this is the right approach to do the functionality.

```
var pdfObject="<object data='"+fullPath+"' type='application/pdf' width='300' height='200'>";
                 pdfObject=pdfObject+ "alt : <a href='"+fullPath+"'>pdffile_url</a> </object>";
                 $("#video").append(pdfObject);.
```

My requirement:With the help of filePath(Eg:C:\Users\arun_abraham06\Desktop\file."any extension"),need to preview the file in html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render a preview icon of the files serverside.

Comment: the files will be in either local system location or in a LAN location. All I need is the preview functionality should take the file path from front end(angular js bind, html5) and display in the same page(in a div).